# Partial keyword match not working when I am trying to create a new column from a pandas data frame in python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, nltk

I have a data frame Description  as mentioned below

```
  Description
```

I am trying to do a keyword search on the description column and I have list of keywords as a list .

My current code checks only exact matches not partial matches.If there are multiple keywords present in the row these will be separated by a delimiter  and populated new column.

My code

```
data=pd.read_excel('path_to_datafile.xlsx')
keywords=['dinner','government','Agents','entertainment','Agent']
keywords_lower = [item.lower() for item in keywords]
s=set(keywords_lower)
data['Keyword'] = data['Description'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(set(x.lower().split()).intersection(s)))
```

How can this be done?

Comment: How can you expect "Commision" in the output, when there is no keyword like this in keywords. Also, how "entertainment" can select "entertains" and "govern" - "Goverment"?  (pay attention that "goverment" has letter "m" after "r", not "n")

Comment: @Alex, it was a typo , i have  edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extractall` will do the job, but you must first build the pattern:

```
...
keywords_lower = [item.lower() for item in keywords]
pattern = '(' + '|'.join('(?:' + i + ')' for i in keywords_lower) + ')'
df['Keyword'] = df['Description'].str.extractall(pattern, re.I).groupby(level=0).agg('/'.join)
```

You would get:

```
                       Description           Keyword
0  Government entertainment people  Govern/entertain
1                  Dinner with CFO            Dinner
2  Commission to Agents government      Agent/govern
```

(`pattern` is here `'((?:dinner)|(?:govern)|(?:agent)|(?:entertain))'`)

Comment: can we  use this logic for multiple input columns at a time and generate like `df['Keyword']=df [['Description1','Description2']].str.extractall()`

Comment: Not directly because `str` only apply to one single Series. At most you could do: `df['Keyword']=(df ['Description1'] + df['Description2']).str.extractall()`.